# Pulling an ACF into a query

Tags: query

I need to include a field from Advanced Custom Fields (5.0) into this query. The field name I need to add is "overall_rating". I'm getting lost on the idea of post meta.

```
    $_query[] = 'SELECT post.ID, post.post_title, post.post_date, YEAR(post.post_date) as post_year, post.post_status, post.comment_count, post.comment_status, post.post_author, post.post_excerpt, term_rel.term_taxonomy_id';

        $_query[] = 'FROM `' . $wpdb->posts . '` AS post';
        $_query[] = 'LEFT JOIN `' . $wpdb->postmeta . '` meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id';
        $_query[] = 'LEFT JOIN `' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '` term_rel ON post.ID = term_rel.object_id';
        $_query[] = 'WHERE post.post_type IN("' . implode('","', $this->post_type_array) . '")';
        $_query[] = 'AND post.post_status IN ( ' . $_post_status . ' )';
        $_query[] = 'AND post.ID = "' . $post->ID . '"';
        $_query[] = 'GROUP BY post.ID';
        $_query[] = 'ORDER BY post_date ' . $this->sort_order;
```

Not as simple as adding:
 SELECT post.ID, post.post_title, postmeta.overall_rating

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a raw query instead of using `WP_Query` with custom fields parameters (`'meta_key' => 'overall_rating'` and `'meta_value' => $acf_overall_rating_field_value`)  ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the database table to see how the field is actually stored. Or you can take a look here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/database-structure/

Comment: Thanks both of you.  Raw query because I was editing some existing code, not starting from scratch. I think I'm going to back track on this and go a different direction.